# Pangaea Reborn? How could we create a new pangea?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, geography

Inspired by this article on Big Think: [Genius or Crazy? Pangaea Reborn](http://bigthink.com/genius-or-crazy/genius-or-crazy-pangea-reborn), how could humanity create a new Pangaea out of our planet?

From what I remember of my earth science class, the amount of energy being spent on tectonic plate movement would be on the order of many times the amount of energy used by humanity every year to only move the continents by inches a year. To move them across an entire ocean would take millions of years worth of that amount of energy.

Comment: Do you have a time frame in mind?

Comment: Technically, wouldn't building a bridge across the Bering Strait get you 80% of the way there?

Comment: @Frostfyre I suppose the timeframe would be "while humans are still alive"

Answer (score 4):

What your geology class teaches is true. Plus, most plates are right now moving **away** from each other (unless your point of reference is on the opposite side of the planet when considering two plates' motion). You would actually have to spend ridiculously high amounts of energy to start pushing them back. Not to mention huge tsunamis, earthquakes, the risk of magnetic reversal, extreme volcanic and orogenic events and whatnot.

And in the end you will have all the landmass together. There is little chance that we would have retained all our scientific progress due to the severely severe calamities that would befall. Plus, in the end the climatic conditions far inland would be extreme. Summers would be scorching while winters would freeze the bones to the core. Plus, very little rainfall in the innermost reaches of this new aggregated landmass.

All in all, don't think about it.

---

And if you ***must*** do that, just wait out and all continents would eventually meet up again. It is going to take up a tremendously long time though.

Nothing else is going to help you much.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to create a new Pangaea.

Comment: @Frostfyre I think the point is, without some ridiculous magitech, you just can't, which is an answer.

Comment: @James The answer was edited after I made my comment.

Comment: The text below the line, yes. But I don't think one could ***really*** make or break something on the scale of continents. So the main point holds, that it's futile to try that at home without a senior's supervision.

Comment: @YoustayIgo Agreed. The simplest answer was always to just wait it out; your answer hadn't mentioned that, however. Besides, the OP wants it done while humans are still around. Not sure if humans can wait around a few million years.

Comment: I got the feeling that OP wants to do it while ***he is around***. So that's why ...